# How to make footer stick close to the text on the last page?

Tags: header-footer, positioning

I want footer to appear immediately after text on the last page, without huge gap.
I used `showframe` package and know that white space comes from the body (is tex adding some sort of `\vskip` or similar so that body height is exactly `\textheight`?). I'm also able to shift footer manually by decreasing `\textheight` for the last page using `changepage` package:

```
\changepage{-10cm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
```

But I need some way to get "true" text height automatically to substitute it as an argument for `changepage`.

And of course there could be (should be!) some better and cleaner way to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe this question offers some help: [Footnotes on bottom except on last page of a chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19290/2693)

Comment: This is a rather uncommon layout. Unless you are required to move the footer because of some state/university style rules, I'd advise against it.

Comment: Well, not strictly state rules, but since footer contains `\hrule`s for signatures (every page should be signed), it should be close to the body so that nothing could be hand-written between.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to move footer contents to the body of the document for the last page:

```
....
\newcommand{\footercontents}{my footer text}
\tcfoot{\footercontents}
\pagestyle{fancy}
....
%last page
\nopagebreak[4]
\thispagestyle{plain}
\footercontents
\end{document}
```

The obvious problem with this solution is ensuring that footer does not hang alone on the last page, i.e. there is no page break between normal text and `\footercontents`. Neither `\nopagebreak` (even with maximum argument) nor `samepage` environment works for me =(