# Footnotes at the bottom of page and end of chapter at the same time

Tags: footnotes

How can I place both explanatory footnotes at the bottom of page and referential footnotes at the end of a chapter? In fact I want to use two kinds of footnotes at same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [footnotes - on the bottom except on last page of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19290/footnotes-on-the-bottom-except-on-last-page-of-chapter)

Comment: You could try to use footnotes and endnotes, but then you will have to think about the numbering, because not every footnote will need an endnote and vice versa, and it would be confusing to have two numbers after each other in the text (may be you can put the endnote in the footnote then, but still use an other set of 'numbers').

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a package for this already.  Like endfloat, endnotes creates a file, so cannot be used more than once.  Manyfoot puts all footnotes at the bottom of the page.  I could do it, but it will take a while.  Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610119/how-to-put-footnotes-in-two-columns/610195?r=SearchResults&s=3|21.4516#610195

Answer (score 3):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) supports  endnotes which it calls `\pagenote`. The notes may be printed at the end of each chapter or all together near the end of the document. You can either identify the notes by numbers (like footnotes) or by a few words from the text to identify the origin of the note; the page number can be used here as well.

The class also supports a variety of footnotes.